# Python - Passing a function into another function

Tags: python, function, first-class-functions

I am solving a puzzle using python and depending on which puzzle I am solving I will have to use a special set of rules. How can I pass a function into another function in Python?

Example

```
def Game(listA, listB, rules):
   if rules == True:
      do...
   else:
      do...

def Rule1(v):
  if "variable_name1" in v:
      return False
  elif "variable_name2" in v:
      return False
  else:
      return True

def Rule2(v):
  if "variable_name3" and "variable_name4" in v:
      return False
  elif "variable_name4" and variable_name1 in v:
      return False
  else:
      return True
```

This is just a pseudo code and therefore not specific but I get the code to compile but I need to know how to call the function `Game` and whether it's correctly defined since rules will be switched for either `Rule1(v)` or `Rule2(v)`.

Answer (score 170):

Just pass it in like any other parameter:

```
def a(x):
    return "a(%s)" % (x,)

def b(f,x):
    return f(x)

print b(a,10)
```

Comment: functions are first-class objects in python. you can pass them around, include them in dicts, lists, etc. Just don't include the parenthesis after the function name. Example, for a function named `myfunction`: `myfunction` means the function itself, `myfunction()` means to call the function and get its return value instead.

Comment: And what if the function is a method on an object and uses a property of that object to do its work?

Comment: What if the functions I pass have a varying number of input arguments? Should I then use keyword arguments?

Comment: What if the two functions are in separate python files?

Answer (score 29):

Treat function as variable in your program so you can just pass them to other functions easily:

```
def test ():
   print "test was invoked"

def invoker(func):
   func()

invoker(test)  # prints test was invoked
```

Comment: Yes. In the example above, the ``invoker`` function would then need to supply those arguments when calling the function.

Answer (score 17):

For passing both a function, and any arguments to the function:

```
from typing import Callable    

def looper(fn: Callable, n:int, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Call a function `n` times

    Parameters
    ----------
    fn: Callable
        Function to be called.
    n: int
        Number of times to call `func`.
    *args
        Positional arguments to be passed to `func`.
    **kwargs
        Keyword arguments to be passed to `func`.

    Example
    -------
    >>> def foo(a:Union[float, int], b:Union[float, int]):
    ...    '''The function to pass'''
    ...    print(a+b)
    >>> looper(foo, 3, 2, b=4)
    6
    6
    6       
    """
    for i in range(n):
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

Depending on what you are doing, it could make sense to define a [`decorator`](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/), or perhaps use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Answer (score 10):

Just pass it in, like this:

```
Game(list_a, list_b, Rule1)
```

and then your Game function could look something like this (still pseudocode):

```
def Game(listA, listB, rules=None):
    if rules:
        # do something useful
        # ...
        result = rules(variable) # this is how you can call your rule
    else:
        # do something useful without rules
```

Answer (score 10):

A function name can become a variable name (and thus be passed as an argument) by dropping the parentheses. A variable name can become a function name by adding the parentheses.

In your example, equate the variable `rules` to one of your functions, leaving off the parentheses and the mention of the argument. Then in your `game()` function, invoke `rules( v )` with the parentheses and the `v` parameter.

```
if puzzle == type1:
    rules = Rule1
else:
    rules = Rule2

def Game(listA, listB, rules):
    if rules( v ) == True:
        do...
    else:
        do...
```