# passing a function to a function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand a code written in python. They are passing mean_squared_error to make_scorer. What does it mean to pass a function as an argument of another function? What does the underscore at the end of  `mean_squared_error_` represent?

```
def fmean_squared_error(ground_truth, predictions):
    fmean_squared_error_ = mean_squared_error(ground_truth, predictions)**0.5
    return fmean_squared_error_

RMSE  = make_scorer(fmean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)
```

Comment: Well, yes, you can pass functions around just like regular values. The receiver is then free to call that function. *mind blown* – The `_` just serves to make the name different; apparently the author couldn't come up with a better name.

Comment: Not sure why the massive downvote hail.

Comment: @AmiTavory my guess would be that this question could easily be answered by googling his own title reading eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349332/python-passing-a-function-into-another-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Python, [everything is an object](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html), including functions. A function `foo` is something that supports using it as `foo(...)`. As opposed to some other languages, therefore, there is nothing special in Python about passing a function to a function. You're just passing a regular object, with the property that the other function can call it as a function.
2. Adding an underscore at the end of an identifier, is a common Python practice for avoiding overwriting existing names. Note that the name of the first function here is `fmean_squared_error`. In the body, the writer used the same name but with an underscore appended, to avoid overwriting the function's identifier. Alternatively, this could have been named, say, `res`.