# What does "take a list of instances of a method" mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What does it mean for a function to take a list of instances of a method in Python?
How would you implement that?

Comment: This is a specification of input, you *cannot* implement the specs of input, these are given to you. It is up to the caller to respect these contracts, not the callee.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is asking you this?

Answer (score 2):

A function in Python is an object. You can store it in a variable or pass it as a parameter to a function. The whole concept of decorators is based on that.

```
# Accepts two instances of a method as input arguments
# Executes the two function instances
def twofuncs(fa, fb):
    fa(5)
    fb(10)

def original_fa(x):
    print("Function a", x)

# Instance of the above function
fa = original_fa

# Executing the main function
twofuncs(fa, fa)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we interpret it literally... Any function is just an object. You can have therefore have instances of functions, and you can place them in a list.

A function...

```
def func():
    pass
```

Takes a list...

```
def func(lst):
    pass
```

of instances of a method...

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y

func([add, add, add])
```

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that you're passing a method reference into a function as an argument.  This has been asked before on this site.  You can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706721/how-do-i-pass-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-python) or perhaps this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349332/python-passing-a-function-into-another-function) for an example of how this is done.