# How to pass a list of function names as a parameter?

Tags: python, function

How to use a function name as a parameter in Python?
For example:

```
def do_something_with(func_name, arg):
    return func_name(arg)
```

where 'func_name' might be 'mean', 'std', 'sort', etc.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
func_list = ['mean', 'std']

for func in func_list:
    x = np.random.random(10)
    print do_something_with(func, x)
```

and of course the result should a successful application of 'mean' and 'std' on my array 'x'.

Comment: pass a list of functions instead. `func_list = [np.mean, np.std]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Passing a function into another function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349332/python-passing-a-function-into-another-function) (although the bulk of the actual question is irrelevant, the root question and answers are valid)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggestet in the comments, pass function objects in a list to your function and call them. This will not just work with `numpy`, but with all Python functions:

```
import numpy as np
func_list = [np.mean, np.std]

for func in func_list:
    x = np.random.random(10)
    print func(x)
```

Make sure the function calls work all the same way, i.e. `x` as first parameter.

The above is pretty similar to how function renaming works:

```
import time

another_sleep = time.sleep
another_sleep(1)  # Sleep for one second
```

You create a function object (`time.sleep`) and assign it to a variable (`another_sleep`). Now you can call it with the variable's name (`another_sleep(1)`).

Answer (score 7):

Tadhg McDonald-Jensen's solution is right because function is first-class citizen in Python. Also, I have another idea:

```
from operator import methodcaller

import numpy as np


func_list = ['mean', 'std']
for func in func_list:
    x = np.random.random(10)
    f = methodcaller(func, x)
    result = f(np)
    print(result)
```

You can use `operator.methodcaller` for some cases.

Comment: `f(np)` here `np` stands for classname which contains the methods `mean` and `std`