# How can a parameter of a function become function?

Tags: python

How a(b) works in this code?

```
def here(a, b):
    print('Hello')
    a(b)
```

Does a become the function? a and b are parameters of the function here. *What is the concept of a(b).*

```
def near(f):
    print(f)
    
here(near, 'Where?')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Passing a function into another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349332/python-passing-a-function-into-another-function)

Comment: `a` must already be a function, or at least a callable object- otherwise an exception will be raised

Comment: `a` doesn't "become" a function. `a` must be an object that implements the `__call__()` function (such as a declared func) or you will get an exception when you call it as `a(b)`.

Comment: In Python, everything is an object. Functions are in fact objects, so you can pass them as argument of other functions

Answer (score 1):

```
def here(a, b):
    print('Hello')
    a(b)
def near(f):
    print(f)
    
here(near, 'Where?')
```

> What is the concept(...)?

This code does rely on that functions in python are *first-class citizens*, [Who Is First-Class Citizen In Programming World?](https://medium.com/ryanjang-devnotes/who-is-first-class-citizen-in-programming-world-b92c67b32635) gives following claim

> A programming language is said to have first-class functions when
> functions in that language are treated like any other variable. For
> example, a function can be passed as an argument to other functions,
> can be returned by another function, and can be assigned as a value to
> a variable.